# Is there a library for a pop out photo viewer like facebook?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, popup

I would like to display an infographic on my page via a pop out like the facebook photo viewer, rather than just have a popup window be created with the image in it.  I just like the UI of a pop out versus a pop up (no window management).

Is there a jQuery/javascript library that accomplishes the pop out functionality?

I'm trying to emulare [visual.ly](http://www.visual.ly) that loads the infographic in a pop out once you click the preview image.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a *lot* of them. [Search Google for "jQuery Lightbox"](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ie=UTF-8&ion=1#hl=en&sugexp=pfwl&tok=PjSHQkjRQRsSxiruQyxEdA&cp=1&gs_id=23&xhr=t&q=jQuery%20lightbox&pq=lightbox&pf=p&sclient=psy-ab&qscrl=1&site=webhp&source=hp&pbx=1&oq=jlightbox&aq=0&aqi=g4&aql=&gs_sm=&gs_upl=&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.,cf.osb&fp=2303290c933ce3a0&ion=1&biw=1264&bih=1287) and at least one of them should match your needs.

Answer (score 1):

For jQuery, try [fancybox](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/), a lightbox alternative.

There is also [this page](http://planetozh.com/projects/lightbox-clones/) which compares different alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

[Yoxvew](http://www.yoxigen.com/yoxview/) is a pretty good one. The downside to it is as far as I know it does not allow for scrolling, so you can't use larger images. There are a ton of these plugins around though. If none of them fit your needs it isn't too hard to make your own, or you can modify an existing library.

Answer (score 1):

The page you link to use [Colorbox.js](http://jacklmoore.com/colorbox/) to view photos.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done simply with two `<div>` tags as well.  One, which blankets the whole page with some semi transparent color or image and has a z-index larger than the whole page.  Two, which has a z-index larger than one, is spaced relevantly, and contains whatever you want to show.  Rolling your own isn't always desirable, as there are plenty of pre-written alternatives pointed out such as fancybox, lightbox, etc., but sometimes it is nice to know your options.